# Should I always use Lambda Expressions for Exception Tests?

Tags: java, exception, junit, lambda, java-8

I always tested my exceptions with annotations.

```
@Test (expected = Exception.class)
public void test1() {
  methodToTest() // throws an exception
}
```

I finally switched to Java 8, and I came across lambda Expressions. Now there is another option to get the desired result.

```
@Test
public void test2() {
  assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> methodToTest());
}

public static <X extends Throwable> Throwable assertThrows(
  final Class<X> exceptionClass, final Runnable block) {
    try {
      block.run();
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
      if (exceptionClass.isInstance(ex))
        return ex;
    }
    fail("Failed to throw expected exception");
    return null;
  }
```

I understand that with the second version you can check for single methods more precisely, and you don't have to worry about other methods within a single test that could throw the expected exception as well. Furthermore, with an "assertThrows" method, all tests can have the same structure, because it all comes down to a call for an assertion.

Besides those two points, **are there any pro arguments for the new way?** For me, it feels like its still superior to go with the annotations, as long as I am only testing a single method within a single test.

Comment: Where are the lambda expressions in this question ?

Comment: "test2" hands over a lambda expression to the assertThrows method, which is handled as a Runnable.

Comment: Are you asking why it is necessary to use a lambda expression? Or why you would do all of this instead of using the @Test (expected = Exception.class) annotation? If it's the latter, you pretty much answered it yourself, those are 2 good points.

Comment: Ups sorry I read too quickly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a third way, the `ExpectedException` jUnit rule:

```
public class SimpleExpectedExceptionTest {
   @Rule
   public ExpectedException thrown= ExpectedException.none();

   @Test
   public void myMethod_throws_no_exception_when_passed_greeting() {
       fixture.myMethod("hello");
   }

   @Test
   public void myMethod_throws_MyException_when_passed_farewell() {
       thrown.expect(MyException.class);
       fixture.myMethod("goodbye");
   }
}
```

I find this clearer than the `@Test (expected = ...)` version, since the expectation goes closer to the method call.

There is also the plain old Java version, which we used to make do with:

```
try {
   fixture.myMethod("should throw");
   fail("Expected an exception");
} catch (MyException e) {
   // expected  
}
```

Which of the many is "better" depends entirely on context. Don't adopt one universally. Pick the one that gives you the clearest test in a given situation.

When you begin coding non-test code in a lambda-centric style, it is likely that you'll find yourself wanting to use the lambda-centric `assertThrows()`.

Comment: With this method, can you do stuff after the call to the method throwing an exception ?

Comment: With the first technique, you can put any code you like following to the throwing method, but it won't get executed when the method throws as expected.

With the plain old Java version, of course you can put anything you like in the catch block, like assertions about the exception, or after the catch block, like assertions about the state of other things afterwards.

Comment: That's what I thought, then what does it bring compared to an annotation ? It's more verbose and does the same thing. Not criticizing, just asking.

Comment: For me, with `(expected = ...)` the assertion is in an unexpected place -- before the test itself. Also you can create more detailed expectations in `ExpectedException`, e.g. `thrown.expectCause(...)`

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to test is that an exception is thrown, the first syntax is better. It is standard, it is concise, and it prevents you from writing the same ugly try-catch over and over.

You could have a test slightly more complicated where you want to assert that an exception is thrown **and** some method is not called. In this case, manually catching the exception is reasonable.

```
@Test
public void test1() {
   DBClient dbClient = spy(new DBClient());
   try {
       new Server().doRequest(new InvalidRequest(), dbClient); 
       fail("should have thrown");
   } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
       verify(dbClient, times(0)).query(any(Query.class));
   }
}
```

Regarding the use on lambdas more specifically, it's up to you. Just note that `Runnable` cannot throw checked exceptions so you would need something like

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingRunnable<E extends Exception> {
     void run() throws E;
}
```

Comment: Side note: using a boolean `hasThrown` and another assert on that is bonkers. Just put `fail("should have thrown") after your `new Server(...)` line and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem with either approach--there is no right or wrong in matters of style; just use the one that best suits each situation.  I suggest that assertThrows should also check for thrown exceptions that aren't of the expected type, and, as @Dici suggests, that a functional interface that allows checked exceptions be used:

```
public static <X extends Throwable> Throwable assertThrows(
        final Class<X> exceptionClass, final CheckedRunnable block) {
    try {
        block.run();
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        if (exceptionClass.isInstance(ex)) {
            return ex;
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Unexpected exception was thrown", ex);
        }
    }
    fail("Failed to throw expected exception");
}

@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedRunnable<R extends RuntimeException> {
    void run () throws Exception;
}
```